# How can I create an PhpStorm hotkey to switch between controller and view/template in custom framework

Tags: phpstorm

The framework layout is like the following

```
/modules/module_name/controller_name.php
/modules/module_name/templates/controller_name.php
```

The controller and (view / template) always has the same name.

Is there anyway to create a hotkey to switch between the two?

Comment: Using existing functionality -- I doubt (do not know any). But by coding custom plugin (and defining custom action there) -- should be no big problem .. except that it has to be done in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into writing a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I created a plugin with the following action and its working well.

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    Project project = e.getProject();
    VirtualFile vFile = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);
    String fileName = vFile != null ? vFile.getName() : null;
    if(fileName == null){
        return;
    }
    String filePath = vFile.getPath();
    String fileDirectory = filePath.replace(fileName,"");

    String newPath;
    if(fileDirectory.contains(File.separator+"templates"+File.separator)){
        newPath = filePath.replace("templates"+File.separator+fileName,fileName);
    }else{
        newPath = filePath.replace(fileName,"templates"+File.separator+fileName);
    }
    VirtualFile newVFile = com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByPath(newPath);
    if (newVFile == null) {
        return;
    }
    FileEditorManager fileEditorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
    fileEditorManager.openFile(newVFile,true,true);
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad that it worked for you. You made plugin pretty fast (did you had past experience with IntelliJ plugins?). If you have not listed your plugin on their plugin site (which make sense if this is to work with some publicly available CMS/framework .. or plugin is customisable (so that user can adjust paths)) ... consider sharing whole plugin source -- can be very useful for people with similar needs (finding some working solution that can be used as sample code/to see how internals works)